# Azure SQL Database connection string with Active Failover with Private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

We have an ASP.Net Web app hosted as Azure App serivce connecting to Azure SQL Server. We have 2 Azure SQL Server one in North and other in South region (For Failover). We have created Private endpoints for both the sql servers:-

```
NorthRegion-devxxxs-sql-server.database.windows.net
SouthRegion-devxxxs-sql-server.database.windows.net
```

Following is the Read/Write listener endpoint from Failover group:-

```
XXXXX-devxxxxs-failovergroup.database.windows.net
```

North is Primary and South is secondary and they are added to Failover group.
AsP.Net Web app connection string uses private endpoint to North Region SQL Server as follows:-

```
  <add name="xxxxxxxx" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:NorthRegion-devxxxs-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dtasbasename;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Admin;Password=YYYYYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

We did a Failover test and SQL Server were switched as South primary and North secondary but our suspicion was its still connecting to North region database due to pvt endpoint so for testing we delted north region database and we got runtime exception.

Then I changed my connection string to use the READ/WRITE Listner and this is how my connection string looked (same user id and password) and still we got runtime exception : Cannot connect to the database. following was the modified connection string using the listener endpoint from failover group:-

```
<add name="xxxxxxxx" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:XXXXX-devxxxxs-failovergroup.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dtasbasename;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Admin;Password=YYYYYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


TCPPING XXXXX-devxxxxs-failovergroup.database.windows.net:1433
```

TCPPing from the App service (Console) works properly for the failovergroup FQDN and returns  Connected (basically App service able to ping the Failover group as well as the Private SQL Endpoint also).

My question here is what should the connection string look like in this scenario where I have 2 SQL Servers in 2 different regions with Private EndPoints and in the Failover group. I am not sure about what should be the Database Server name that goes in web.config connection string so that it can automatically connect to the Secondary Server if Primary Server goes down.

Any help?

Comment: Is that you use Regional VNet Integration to connect Azure SQL in Azure app service?

Comment: @JimXu both my Azure SQL Server and my Azure web -app service are in the same VNet but in two different SubNet  which are in the same NorthCentral region(No NSG rule applied and I can connect to individual Private End point of the SQL just that I cant connect using the Failover Listener.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can tcpping the Secondary Server in your app service?

Comment: yes @JimXu I am able to tcpping secondary server from app service and get a response.back.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you configure Vnet fro your app service to connect SQL?

Comment: @JimXu I have added the Vnet thru App Services Network menu (Configure Vnet) and added the Subnet from the Vnet. This Subnet has permissions on the SQL Server hence I am able to connect it when I use the Private endpoint of the primary Server just that when I use the failover endpoint listener it doesnt work.

Comment: Is that you refer to the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/private-web-app/private-web-app to do that?

Comment: yes thats correct @JimXu I have used the above document and have the app settings entries as well

Comment: Could you please tell me how you integrate VNET?  Region or gateway : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet?

Comment: Integration is thru App Gateway